# With React styled-components, how to add a Modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, styled-components

I'm learning how to add styled-components to my React app. I'm at the point now where I want to add a Modal Dialog to my app and unsure how to approach this problem with styled components.

For those that use styled-components, how did you add a Modal to your app? Do you need to use a styled-component library for this, a react modal library or a jQuery solution? What's the right way to add a Modal to a React styled-component app?

Comment: styled-components makes no difference here. you can use any modal solution. it's also quite easy to write your own modal

Comment: Which modal solution do you recommend ?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal

Comment: I would suggest writing your own Modal component and attaching an outside click event handler (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside). You would have more flexibility for creating complex and dynamic modals than you would just using a package.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a library that provides a `Modal` component, you can wrap it using styledComponents:

```
const WrapperModal = styled(Modal)`

    /* yourStyleHere; */

`;
```

Then call **WrapperModal** to used instead of your **Modal** component.

Comment: This only works if the library-provided Modal supports a `className` parameter on the top level modal, and that it uses a proper styling hierarchy. If the parameter name is something other than `className`, but uses the same semantics, then you might be able to specify an alternate name, but there is no guarantee. For example, [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/603) requires some pretty hefty workarounds to use with Styled Components, whereas [react-bootstrap-modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) works out of the box.